# Can TypeScript extend an instance's type after calling the instance's method?

Tags: typescript, class, methods, instance, defineproperty

I have a JS library that I'm trying to create types for, imagine the following class:

```js
class Table {

  register(...fields) {
    fields.forEach(field => {
      Object.defineProperty(this, field, {
        get: () => {
          console.log(`Accessed ${field}`);
          return 1;
        },
      })
    })
  }

}
```

and then you could use `Table` this way:

```js
let table = new Table(); 
table.register(["uuid", "name", "url"]);
table.name; // has a value of 1 and prints "Accessed name"
```

Writing a declaration for the class seems easy

```js
class Table {
  register(...fields: string[]): void;
}
```

However, I don't know whether it's possible for TypeScript to extend the instance's type after calling `table.register()`.

```js
let table = new Table(); 
table.register(["uuid", "name", "url"]);
table.name; // TypeScript error, `name` is not a field of Table
```

I know it's possible to change the JS code to return the instance itself and then TypeScript could simply return a different type, but in the case the function doesn't return anything, is it possible to tell TypeScript that the instance's type has slightly changed after the call?

Comment: You can make `register()` an [assertion method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjXYvm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Seems like this does fit my need! Please do write ba answer, thanks!

Comment: I guess there's no workaround for having to write the type annotation on the instance, mind explaining why it is mandatory?

Comment: I will explain in my answer, which I’ll write when I get a chance (on mobile now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn `void`-returning functions and methods into [*assertion functions*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) by annotating their return type with an `asserts` predicate.  This allows the compiler to interpret a call to that function as a [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) of the apparent type of one of the arguments (or `this` in the case of an assertion method).

Adding properties to an existing type is considered a narrowing, according to  TypeScript's [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system).  That's because object types are open/extensible and not sealed/exact; given types `interface Foo {x: string}` and `interface Bar extends Foo {y: string}`, you can say that every `Bar` is a `Foo` but not vice versa, and therefore that `Bar` is narrower than `Foo`. (Note that there is a longstanding open request to support exact types at [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), and people often are confused into thinking that TypeScript types are exact because of [excess property warnings on object literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks); I won't digress further here, but the main point is that extra properties constitute a *narrowing* and not an *incompatibility*).

So, because `register()` is a `void`-returning method which serves to add properties to `this`, you can get the behavior you're looking for by making `register()` into an assertion method.

---

Here's one way to do it:

```
class Table {
  register<P extends string>(...fields: P[]
  ): asserts this is this & Record<P, 1> {
    fields.forEach(field => {
      Object.defineProperty(this, field, {
        get: () => {
          console.log(`Accessed ${field}`);
          return 1;
        },
      })
    })
  }
}
```

The return type `asserts this is this & Record<P, 1>` implies that a call to `table.register(...fields)` will cause the type of `table` (the *value* called `this` in `asserts this`) to be narrowed from whatever it starts as (the [*type* called `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) in `this & Record<P, 1>`) to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of its starting type with `Record<P, 1>` (using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)), where `P` is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the values passed in as `fields`.

That means that by starting with `table` of type `Table`, a call to `table.register("x", "y", "z")` should narrow `table` to `Table & Record<"x" | "y" | "z", 1>`, which is equivalent to `Table & {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}`.

---

Let's see it in action, before exploring some important caveats:

```
let table: Table = new Table();
// ----> ^^^^^^^ <--- this annotation is REQUIRED for this to work
table.register("uuid", "name", "url");
table.name; // has a value of 1 and prints "Accessed name"
table.hello; // error
table.register("hello");
table.hello; // okay
```

That's more or less what you wanted, I think.  The compiler allows you to access `table.name` after the call the `table.register("uuid", "name", "url")`.  I also add a `"hello"` field, and you can see that the compiler is unhappy about accessing it before it is created, but happy afterward.

---

So, hooray. Now for the caveats:

The first one is shown above; you are required to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the `table` variable with the `Table` type in order for its assertion method to behave.  If you don't, you get this awful thing:

```
let table = new Table();
table.register("uuid", "name", "url"); // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Assertions require every name in the
// call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation
```

This is a basic limitation with assertion functions and assertion methods.  According to [microsoft/TypeScript#32695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695), the PR that implemented assertion functions (emphasis mine):

> A function call is analyzed as an assertion call ... when ...
> each identifier in the function name references an entity with an explicit type ... An entity is considered to have an explicit type when it is declared as a function, method, class or namespace, or as a variable, parameter or property with an explicit type annotation. (**This particular rule exists so that control flow analysis of potential assertion calls doesn't circularly trigger further analysis.**

And [microsoft/TypeScript#33622](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33622) is the PR that implemented the particular error message above (before this it would just silently fail to narrow).  It's not great, and it bites people every so often.

It would be great if it could be fixed, but [according to this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34596#issuecomment-548084070) on the related issue [microsoft/TypeScript#34596](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34596):

> The issue here is that we need the information about the assertness of a function early enough in the compilation process to correctly construct the control flow graph. Later in the process, we can *detect* if this didn't happen, but can't really *fix* it without performing an unbounded number of passes. We warned that this would be confusing but everyone said to add the feature anyway

So I guess if you want this to work, you're going to need an explicit type annotation.

---

Also, a general problem with [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) is that its effects do not cross function boundaries.  You can read all about it at [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  This implies that *closures* over narrowed values will lose their narrowing, perhaps surprisingly:

```
let table: Table = new Table();
table.register("hello");
table.hello; // okay

function doSomething() {
  table.hello; // error!
}
```

Inside `doSomething()`, the type of `table` has been widened back to `Table`.  The standard workaround for such cases is to "save" the narrowed state by assigning the narrowed value to a new `const` variable, and then use the `const` inside the function:

```
const _table = table;
function doSomething2() {
  _table.hello; // okay
}
```

This works because `_table` is assigned from `table`, whose apparent type at the time of the assignment contains a `hello` property.  And therefore `_table` will always and forever have such a property, even inside closures.

And so, that's great, but... well, it's not *very* much different from having the `register()` function return a new value of the narrowed type and having you use the new value instead of the old one, which is the approach you mentioned in the question.

---

So depending on how you use `Table` instances, assertion methods might be more trouble than they're worth.  Still, they do exist, and are exactly what you were asking about in your question, and they do kind of sort of work sometimes, so you should keep them in mind!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqYCMQFNoG8CwAoa0BOyA5gJYQAuyeAPAArTIAeFAdgCYzl7HOEB8AFADphAM2LIQ7AFzQaAbQC62XAEoZkCJTIwyAC1LQDegwDJoAJWTAA9nla0ANNACMvdMtzQxE9oJG2AUTBgXX5vSWgAXjdMHE9cAHkEACsrMkFWZDFmZBo8awAHLQBPfmMIJ3DWJ1j4+MJkMhl+FSiYjzrPG2YIaxRBEGtCfgADAEFgYGQoZFZoABI0KoBfEZUAbg7O-EaAVzxmF024zuWHLdxllS2rj2Xse6xsFDJoMkQUGXgkVEjoHIA7nAPsgWscAPTg6AAWlh0LcAD0kciEdAqHC3voYGBmMxrO8yMRrIcDOYAgBFACqAEkyQARLy2TFGazQAG2ADW2HeP0EBBI5Eo-AARLtdsRWMKnMLmGAALbIKXQUV4EDCjbckGCWUK9bQSHQXSQaBgaAANzAIF2qGsIhcJrY0AKXGY2mVEymMzmOsVmt5ugkgz1Bso+Twfv6-NIFDwIoDIEG6uOPP68aD+qh1g5YGK2GwPogBWCqDGuPxYEJxIAwmAzcgK+44i83iCov9kEDvigwR4U8g+URo0LReLJdKfUqVWqNhn6HgwwBCDyQgB+a-XG7XaNh0DGMzwlZ6OwAjuKCPQ63hiv95ahuJjkMuocBLSAW3gGq8yKyEKhMqAwAIOYAWIPQHXoBgChAYhgFAt5iiKB08QJIlmAePMsALIspmgKtBggfZkBrOsG1iDxmz7L5Wz+QFgR+Hs4gNOF4WgFFkW3HdyiQ8tD0MGAySpWkAgZfw8GZHRWXZPAuTiPsBwFGMRTFCVJwnaV9mnY5cDkn1gyhI1sXNS1rWgW17RxOZnW4N1hQ9aZNG9W9hV7LU02sPS5zDFzeSjQVY2FNyk281NA3c2csxzDwRF2ZhgF41hrAAZWsBVjB4FpG3iOS3I80NbCXOJHlwbpyGgAB9Ps2z7LSvBiuLUOgBLktS-QeAAJgy2pPAq1zQo8iLc0Kh4gA)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I would refractor `register` if I could, but sadly I can't!